# machen sollen werden soll?

Tags: word-order, modal-verb

Obwohl ich ein deutscher Muttersprachler bin, habe ich mit der Formulierung von Pflichten, die erst in der Zukunft entstehen, manchmal Probleme. Ein ganz konkretes Beispiel:

Eine Kundin möchte, dass ich aus Daten mehrerer Jahre, die sie mir bereitgestellt hat, Listen mit E-Mail-Adressen extrahiere. Diese Listen soll ich ihr dann übergeben. Danach ist geplant, dass sie diese Listen zu einer aktuellen Liste zusammenführt (dabei alte Adressen löscht und neue Adressen, die in meinem Extrakten noch nicht enthalten sind, einfügt). Aus dieser konsolidierten Liste soll ich in einem nachfolgenden Schritt eine Verteilerliste für ein bestimmtes E-Mail-Programm machen. Die Roh-Listen habe ich fertig. Nun möchte ich ihr diese Listen schicken, und ihr dabei folgendes schrieben:

> Ich möchte dich nun bitten, aus diesen Listen der Jahre 2010 bis 2015 eine konsolidierte Liste für das Jahr 2016 zu machen, aus der ich dann die Verteilerliste für dein Programm ...

Wie ist dieser Satz grammatisch korrekt zu einem Ende zu bringen, wenn im fehlenden Teil noch diese Wörter vorkommen sollen:

- machen
- sollen
- werden

Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass ich verpflichtet bin, das zu tun (»ich soll machen«), und ich möchte zum Ausdruck bringen, dass ich das nicht jetzt soll, sondern in der Zukunft (nämlich erst nach erhalt Ihrer Antwort) (»ich werde machen«).

Irgendwie scheinen sich »sollen« und »werden« gegenseitig auszuschließen, wenn sie gemeinsam mit »machen« verwendet werden. Ohne »machen« würde etwas in der Form von »ich werde sollen« rauskommen, was auch genau ausdrückt, dass ich erst in der Zukunft verpflichtet bin etwas zu tun. Aber dann fehlt das was zu tun ist, nämlich »eine Verteilerliste machen«.

Also wie ist dieser Satz zu beenden?

Mir ist natürlich klar, dass man dieses Problem durch Wahl einer anderen Formulierung vermeiden kann, und das werde ich in meinem E-Mail an meine Kundin auch tun. Aber hier im Deutsch-Forum frage ich ganz ausdrücklich nach einem Ende für genau den oben stehenden Satz.

Comment: _… machen soll und werde_ oder _… werde machen sollen_

Comment: Ich würde einfach mit _soll_ enden. Auch wenn die Aufgabe erst in der Zukunft fällig wird, so hast du sie trotzdem in der Gegenwart schon erhalten, das Soll ist also in dem Sinne schon festgelegt.

Comment: *...machen **müssen** werde...* hört sich mMn besser als *...machen **sollen** werde* an (ist aber Geschmackssache) und *...werde machen sollen...* Zu mehrfachem Infinitiv in einem Satz (habe ich heute schon in eine andere Antwort geschrieben): Duden sagt, das solle man aus Verständlichkeitsgründen mit alternativen Formulierungen vermeiden (aber das willst du ja explizit nicht). Grammatikalisch *richtig* sind mMn aber beide Formen und damit Reihenfolgen.

Comment: Um noch ein bisschen mit den Infinitiven zu spielen: *...zu machen haben werde...* drückt an sich genau aus, was du sagen willst.

Comment: .... generiere. Wenn eh abgesprochen ist, dass das die Vorgehensweise sein soll, und Du das tun wirst, würde ich auf die Unterstreichung, dass Du es auch tun sollst, verzichten, da dies nach einem Widerwillen klingt.

Comment: _... machen soll_ müßte reichen, das Adverb 'dann' legt die zeitliche Abfolge bereits fest und damit insb., daß deine Arbeit in der Zukunft anfällt.

Comment: Ich würde ganz einfach "machen werde" schreiben; das "dann" drückt bereits eindeutig aus, dass das voranstehende vorher passieren muss.

Comment: Meines Erachtens kann man nicht zugleich ausdrücken, dass man es machen wird sollen und auch machen wird. "Ich werde es, nach Erhalt Ihrer  Antwort, wie vereinbart erledigen" umschifft das Problem.

Comment: Die zugrunde liegende Annahme ist schon nicht ganz richtig: Es geht nicht um "Pflichten, die erst in der Zukunft entstehen", sondern um Pflichten, die jetzt schon bestehen, aber erst in der Zukunft fällig sind. Denn entstanden ist die Pflicht bereits, als ihr den Vertrag schlosst. Folglich ist "machen soll" in jeder Hinsicht unbedenklich.

Answer (score 2):

Im Nebensatz steht das Prädikat am Ende, und bei mehrteiligen Prädikaten kommt die finite Form zum Schluss.

Ausnahme: Das Hilfsverb **haben** muss (fast) immer *vor* den Infinitiven (Verb + Modalverb) stehen:

> Ist es das, was Du *hast wissen wollen*?

Dagegen ist die Stellung von **werden** hier wahlfrei:

> Das ist es, was Du *wirst schreiben sollen*.
>
> Das ist es, was Du *schreiben sollen wirst*.

Dein Satz darf also mit „werde machen sollen“ oder „machen sollen werde“ enden.

Quelle: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Praedikat/index.html?MenuId=Sentence52#Anchor-Ausnahme-35882)

Allerdings finde ich den Futur bei *sollen* grundsätzlich bedenklich. Ich bin mir noch nicht sicher, ob ich Dich das so *schreiben lassen wollen werde* / *werde schreiben lassen wollen*…

Answer (score -1):

> Ich möchte dich nun bitten, aus diesen Listen der Jahre 2010 bis 2015
>   eine konsolidierte Liste für das Jahr 2016 zu machen, aus der ich dann
>   die Verteilerliste für dein Programm **machen sollen werde**.

Es würde allerdings besser klingen mit *anzufertigen haben werde*. Mit dieser Wortgruppe kannst du eventuell auch die Grammatik besser nachvollziehen.